# Adding project as dependency in XCode 4.x

Tags: xcode, dependencies

With the revamp of XCode I am having a lot of trouble working out how to add make one xcodeproj dependent on another. It was hard enough to work out before but now I am just stuck.

If I drag lib.xcodeproj into app.xcodeproj it just shows up as an item in the project tree and I can't expand it or see build products for linking.

Can someone give me the correct sequence for adding lib.xcodeproj as a dependency to app.xcodeproj (ie it will build if necessary and link to app)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Ahhh just worked out that the reason the lib project was being added as a useless non-expanding item was because I had the lib project open in another window. XCode gave me no indication that this was what the problem was, so I was lucky to stumble across it.

Once I had closed the other window I was able to add the lib project and it showed up correctly as an expandable subtree, as well as now being visible for selection in the app target dependencies.

Comment: Has this and should this be filed as a bug with Apple?

Comment: Wasted 2 hours trying to figure this out, you just saved me a lot of time! Thanks!

Comment: Wow. That's just plain stupid by the Xcode team. Thanks a lot for sharing, you saved me lots of time!

Comment: can't believe. Apple should think about that!

Comment: 8O This is crazy ! had this issue and found the reason here, thanks a lot for that !

Comment: unreal what a colossal waste of time the XCode gui is

Comment: crazy well spotted @intepid. If I could give you 10 votes I would!

Comment: Jesus... About 90 minutes wasted on that crap! Thank you!

Comment: I was running into this problem and like @Goles I had to restart Xcode before it started working correctly.

Comment: Even if the other open project merely references the same secondary project you are attempting to refer to, that silly condition occurs.

Comment: still true in XCode5.01. how lame

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It saved my time. Its a wired issue with Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

The Xcode docs don't seem to be available online just now, so you'll have to search the documentation that came with Xcode for the following references. However, you'll find the information you're looking for under the following headings in *Xcode Project Management Guide*:

- Managing Targets (Adding a Target Dependency)
- Referencing Other Projects

Answer (score 1):

check out BuildKit project https://github.com/davidmorford/BuildKit .
It damatically reduce project dependency management effort.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to add the path to Classes of the lib project to tell your project where to find Header find

- Go to build settings, find "Header Search Path", enter full path to the Classes folder