# Xcode project does not see changes made to linked library

Tags: xcode

**Developing in**: Xcode 5

**Setup**: Workspace contains two projects (workspace and projects are pre-existing).  Project one is an iPad app, project two is a framework library used by project one.

**Issue**:  Upon getting code from repository, the project app works as it should; no issues.  I then make modifications to the library project (add a new method to an existing class in the library project and build... no errors) and add code to the app project to call this new method in the library project's class (***Code completion sees the new method, then build... no errors***).  Then I ***run/debug*** the app project (whether on iOS device or simulator, it doesn't matter).  When I get to the line in the app project that calls the new method of the class in the library project I get the following error:

> Unrecongnized selector sent to instance 0x16665af0

I've had better Objective-C coders look at it and the code itself is good.  I've also followed the suggestions of the links below, but the issue still remains.

> [Changing the source of a static library needs clean and build in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204364/changing-the-source-of-a-static-library-needs-clean-and-build-in-xcode-4)
>
> [How should I manage dependencies across projects in an Xcode workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483909/how-should-i-manage-dependencies-across-projects-in-an-xcode-workspace)
>
> http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/

This code is for a commercial app so suggestions such as "Open file x or y and edit it manually" cannot be accepted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the unrecognized selector error does it show the class that the selector is sent to?  It should.  Is it the proper class?  If not it could be a improper pointer issue.  Also, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding all (possibly even cleaning the build folder)?

Comment: The issue has been solved, although it still does not make sense to me...  Previously, project two was linked to project one as a framework (project_two.framework) via the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of the "Build Phases" window.  We removed that linkage and replaced it with "project_two.a". We also had to make sure that "project_two.a" was set up as a build target in our current scheme (click and hold current scheme->Edit Scheme->Build-> click plus sign and selected "project_two.a" from the list.  Now everything works as expected.  Anybody know why that would matter?