# Drag and drop XCodeProj into another XCodeProj not giving me the option to copy

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-plot

I'm trying to "install" core plot 0.4.

The first instruction is to drag and drop the XCodeProj file into my own project. I do this. Normally when I drag and drop images or the such like it asks me if I want to copy the file into my own project. However for some reason its not asking me, its just creating a reference.

I'm not sure what the difference is, and whether it will still work or not with a reference, its just the first instruction (http://recycled-parts.blogspot.com/2011/07/setting-up-coreplot-in-xcode-4.html) says to click the "copy into folder" checkbox.

However that whole dialogue doesn't come up. I drag and drop and it puts the xcodeproj into mine without anything happening!

*confused* lol

Thanks

Comment: if you dont get the option just copy it yourself into the destination folder and add it from there, then the reference will point to our own project's folder. Otherwise Xcode always just references to the original file destination - which is not really a problem - until you change something in your files structure. I always just do the manual copy and never got a problem again...

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem and it's driving me crazy. 5 minutes ago it dragged it correctly. Now it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: My solution works, but the reason it works is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373575/264947

--

This is what I did to fix it:

1. Close Xcode.
2. Open Xcode and create a new workspace.
3. File > Add files to "Workspace".
4. Add the first project.
5. Build to make sure it builds correctly.
6. File > Add files to "Workspace".
7. Add the second project.
8. Build to make sure it builds correctly.
9. Drag one project into another.

Now, be careful with the next step:

Erase the second standalone project but choose **REMOVE REFERENCES. **

There. Now you should have one project as a dependent of another project.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to do it! :) I can't remember how I got around it now... but this seems like a suitable workaround.